# set value for default selected option in ionic 4

Tags: ionic-framework

I am using ionic 4 and creating edit form. I want to show selected option in select box. I have used patch value but its not working.
This is my code

**Form**

```
<ion-item no-padding>
    <ion-label position="floating">Category</ion-label>
    <ion-select interface="action-sheet" [formControl]="formObj.controls['item_category']" >
    <ion-select-option *ngFor="let category of categories" value="{{category.c_id}}">{{category.c_title}}</ion-select-option>
    </ion-select>            
</ion-item>
```

**.ts**

```
categories : any = [{"c_id":1,"c_title":"Phone"},
                    {"c_id":2,"c_title":"jewelry"}];


constructor(private formBuilder: FormBuilder){  
    this.formObj = formBuilder.group({  
        item_category: ['', Validators.compose([Validators.required])]
    }); 

    this.formObj.patchValue({
        item_category: 2,
    });         
}
```

Comment: Can you please share complete form of ts and value you are setting in item_category

Answer (score 3):

### html

```
<ion-content>
  <form [formGroup]="myform">
    <ion-item no-padding>
      <ion-label position="floating">Category</ion-label>
      <ion-select interface="action-sheet" formControlName="item_category">
        <ion-select-option *ngFor="let category of categories" value="{{category.c_id}}">{{category.c_title}}</ion-select-option>
      </ion-select>            
    </ion-item>
  </form>
  {{myform.value | json}}
</ion-content>
```

### ts

```
export class HomePage {
  myform;
  categories = [
    {
      c_id: 1,
      c_title: 'Category 1'
    }, {
      c_id: 2,
      c_title: 'Category 2'
    }
  ];
  constructor(public loadingCtrl: LoadingController) {
    this.myform = new FormGroup({
      item_category: new FormControl()
    });

    this.myform.patchValue({
      item_category: '2',
    });
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks its working. There is a one more problem that when i set the value in quotes like '2' then it works otherwise its not working. Can you please solve my this issue

Comment: Can you please try value={{category.c_id}}. without double quote

Comment: Yes i tried it. But still not selecting default value

Answer (score 0):

Just use `[(ngModel)]` to bind the actual value property with `ion-select`.

```
<ion-select interface="action-sheet" [(ngModel)]="selectedCategoryId" >
      <ion-select-option *ngFor="let category of categories" value="{{category.c_id}}">{{category.c_title}}</ion-select-option>
</ion-select>
```

**ExampleComponent.ts**

```
export class ExampleComponent {

  selectedCategoryId= 11;

}
```

Answer (score 0):

html

```
<ion-item no-padding>
   <ion-label>Category</ion-label>
   <ion-select interface="action-sheet" [formControl]="formObj.controls['item_category']" [compareWith]="compareFn">
      <ion-select-option *ngFor="let category of categories" [value]="category">{{category.c_title}}</ion-select-option>
   </ion-select>            
</ion-item>
```

ts

```
compareFn(e1: any, e2: any): boolean {
  return e1 && e2 ? e1.c_id == e2.c_id : e1 == e2;
}

categories : any = [{"c_id":1,"c_title":"Phone"},
                    {"c_id":2,"c_title":"jewelry"}];


constructor(private formBuilder: FormBuilder){  
    this.formObj = formBuilder.group({  
        item_category: ['', Validators.compose([Validators.required])]
    }); 

    this.categories.forEach(element => {
      if(element.c_id == 2) {
        this.formObj.controls['item_category'].patchValue(
          element
        )
      }
    }); 
}
```